# Reset the id property of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this

```
const initialState = [
  {
    id: 1, author: 'author 1', title: 'Book 1', category: 'Category 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2, author: 'author 2', title: 'Book 2', category: 'Category 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3, author: 'author 3', title: 'Book 3', category: 'Category 3',
  },
];
```

if one object is removed, for example; the object with id of 2 is removed. I want to reset the id properties of the remaining properties so they follow an order of 1, 2, 3...

I have done this with;

```
let id = 1
state.forEach(object => {
  object.id = id
  id += 1
})
```

Is there a much better way to do this? like using the map function?

Comment: No, your way looks fine.

Comment: Define "better".  What metrics do we use to determine the correct answer?  If you want suggestions on your code, try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Stack Overflow is meant to help with fixing problems with non-working code.

Comment: Why don't you just use the array index for the item?  No need to manually reconfigure it if an element in the array is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be improved just by using the index

```
state.forEach((object, index) => {
  object.id = index + 1
})
```

You can also use `map` function as you suggested but it will return a new array

```
const newArray = state.map((object, index) => {
  object.id = index + 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow immutable practices (if that's what you mean by better), you can use the spread operator (or Object.assign):

```js
const initialState = [
  {
    id: 1, author: 'author 1', title: 'Book 1', category: 'Category 1',
  },
  // commented out for demonstration: this element would be "removed".
  //{
    //id: 2, author: 'author 2', title: 'Book 2', category: 'Category 2',
  //},c
  {
    id: 3, author: 'author 3', title: 'Book 3', category: 'Category 3',
  },
];

const newState = initialState.map((obj, i) => ({ ...obj, id: i + 1 }));

console.log(initialState)
console.log(newState)
```